# scrapy spider scrapes same data multiple times

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

So I was trying to scrape some reviews online with scrapy. I looped through a container where all my items resides to  reduce the number of request and makes the spider faster. The csv I get after completing the whole scraping shows that the spider duplicates data collected sometimes in over 20 rows or more.
However, when I do not loop through the container, the spider is painfully slow, stops scraping after a few pages but returns the data correctly.

I also generated next pages by changing the url values as shown in the code below. I did it so because the html do not have a value of href for the next page icon.

I don't know what's wrong. I need help please!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from yelp.items import YelpItem
import urllib.parse
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class RestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rest'
    start_urls = ['https://www.yelp.com/biz/burma-superstar-san-francisco-2?osq=Restaurants/']
    

def parse(self, response):
    pages = [str(i) for i in range(0,6800,20)]
    for page in pages:
        url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/burma-superstar-san-francisco-2?osq=Restaurants&start='+page
        yield Request(urllib.parse.urljoin(response.url, url))
        
        
    selectors = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'lsidebarActionsHoverTarget')]")
    for selector in selectors:
        yield self.parse_item(selector, response)


def parse_item(self,selector,response):
    l=ItemLoader(item=YelpItem(),selector = response)
    l.default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
    l.add_xpath('date', './/span[@class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--mid__373c0__jCeOG text-align--left__373c0__2XGa-"]/text()')
    l.add_xpath('location', './/span[@class="lemon--span__373c0__3997G text__373c0__2Kxyz text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa- text-weight--bold__373c0__1elNz text-size--small__373c0__3NVWO"]/text()')
    l.add_xpath('review', './/p[contains(@class, "comment")]/span/text()')
    l.add_xpath('rating', './/div[contains(@class,"i-stars")]/@aria-label')
    return l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
def parse_item(self,selector,response):
    l=ItemLoader(item=YelpItem(),selector = response)
```

Your code creates multiple selectors, but you never use them. Instead, you always pass `response` to your item loader.

Comment: I thought I'm using the selectors when I specified. Selector =response instead of response = response. Please how should I write the code to make use of the selectors.

Comment: You need `selector=selector`. You are *technically* using a selector, but it's always the same one (`response.selector`)

Comment: Thanks a million it worked like magic. But I'm still confused about the difference between selector =response and selector=selector. I used the former for one of my spiders before and it worked. Don't know why it didn't work in this case